# Focus removed while typing in edit text

Tags: android, focus, android-edittext

I have an `EditText`

```
serialText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pinText);
```

Now onclick of somebutton, I should get the focus to edit text to write something. But when I click inside of edit text to write, focus is getting removed, i.e., whatever i type does not appear in the edit text

This is the code to do that,

```
public void method(View v) {


arrowButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


@Override

public void onClick(View v) {

    serialNumber = serialText.getText().toString();

        if (serialNumber.equals("")) {
     } else {


}


} }...
```

Here if I don't type anything it comes to if loop without any problem, but samething is not happening for else part.

Can you please help me?

This is my full code

```
public void onClick(View v) {

    if (v.getId() == R.id.pinBtn) {

        arrowButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.arrowBtn);

        serialText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pinText);
        serialText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        arrowButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        //serialNumber = serialText.getText().toString();
        arrowButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                serialNumber = serialText.getText().toString();
                if (serialNumber.equals("")) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Please enter the serial number",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else {

                    isRegularSerialNumber(serialNumber);

                    String encodedserialNumber = Base64.encodeToString(
                            serialNumber.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);

                    receiveSerialData(encodedserialNumber);

                    if (serialResponse.equals("Validated Successfully!")) {
                        showAudio(v);
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Invalid Serial Number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                .show();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem finally, the problem was when we keep an edit text in the listview and when try to write inside that, keyboard pushes the listview up. So we need to add the property  android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" to the listview or to the activity containing the list view in the manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `serialNumber.equals("")`, try replacing it with:

```
serialNumber.length() == 0
```

or

```
serialNumber.matches("")
```

Comment: `serialNumber.equals("")` should not cause any problem

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted is  `onClick()` of `arrowButton`, you should post `onClick()` of `serialText`

Comment: serialText.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
     serialNumber = serialText.getText().toString();

    }
   });